# How can a Wordpress feed be displayed on another site using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, wordpress, feed

I've played with a few snippets I found, as well as the somewhat old plugin jFeed (which never worked for me at all). I am in need of displaying Wordpress posts, WP 3.5.1, in a content slider on another site. The site puts out the standard built-in .com/feed that comes default with Wordpress. Can this be done effectively with jQuery 1.3.2 (apologies, but they will not upgrade)?

Comment: It can be done with plain javascript, the jQuery version shouldn't affect your capabilities. If the feed is available as JSONP, you can get it directly with jQuery, otherwise you'll have to create a server-side proxy on the server that is trying to display the feed that gets the data.

Comment: Can you recommend any existing plugins or snippets?

Comment: I suppose I can try the JSON feed output plugin. Can you point me in the direction of any good sources I can study to learn how to take in and output using JSON (I'm familiar with it, but not experienced working with it)?

Comment: For example, how to request the data using jsonp? That can be as simple as `$.getJSON("http://myblog.com/feed/?callback=?",function(data){ ... });`

Comment: Or you can skip the jsonp plugin and use YQL. http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gfeed check out this solution 
http://www.w3cgallery.com/w3c-blog/jquery/how-to-fetch-rss-feed-by-jquery

Comment: Looks like I'd need a Google AJAX Feed API key for that one to work. Not sure if that'll go well within the project I'm doing.

Comment: The google loader doesn't require a key anymore you can just remove it as explained in this article [link]https://developers.google.com/loader/signup